# Capturar checkbox JS

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Cordial Saludo

Tengo unos checkbox traidos desde php

```
 echo "<div class='form-check'>
                          <label class='form-check-label'>
                          <input class='form-check-input' id='protocolo' class='protocolo' type='checkbox' value=".$Puntaje.">  
                            ".$Indicador."                          
                          </label>
                        </div>";
```

Me mostraria esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es capturar los value de todos con un boton

```
var protocolo_puntaje = $("#protocolo").val();
      alert(protocolo_puntaje);
```

Eso solo me captura uno.

Espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: No puedes usar id porque el id debe de ser unico.  Utiliza clases en su lugar.

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es obtener el valor de todos los checkbox que seleccionas usa el siguiente codigo o te puedes dar una idea:

**TU PHP**

```
echo "<div class='form-check'>
                          <label class='form-check-label'>
                          <input name='checkbox[]' class='form-check-input' id='protocolo' class='protocolo' type='checkbox' value=".$Puntaje.">  
                            ".$Indicador."                          
                          </label>
                        </div>";
```

**JS**

```
var protocolo_puntaje = [];
protocolo_puntaje = $(':checkbox:checked').serializeArray();
console.log(protocolo_puntaje );
```

Espero te funcione.

Comment: No me captura nada, soy nuevo en estos temas :c

Comment: Vale, la verdad es que no hay suficiente codigo para hacerlo mas detallado, intenta hacer lo siguiente, mira la respuesta.

Comment: Perfecto. Gracias